# How to return all records in a column if where clause parameter is null using laravel?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.8, laravel-query-builder

```
$loantype = $request['regloan_type'];

    $loans = Loan::select('date_release')
               ->where('invalid',false)
               ->where('transaction_year', $transyear)
               ->where('loan_type', $loantype)
               ->get();
```

If variable `$loantype` returns null then I want to select all the record in that column. How to do that in laravel where clause?

I have used `if else statement` to get what I want. But is there a way I can do that without using `if else statement`?

Code:

```
$loantype = (empty($request['regloan_type'])) ? null : $request['regloan_type'];

if($loantype==null){

    $loans = Loan::select('date_release')
           ->where('invalid',false)
           ->where('transaction_year', $transyear)
           ->get();
}else{

    $loans = Loan::select('date_release')
           ->where('invalid',false)
           ->where('transaction_year', $transyear)
           ->where('loan_type', $loantype)
           ->get();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the condition in query. But check below code that will add more nice look to your code.

```
$loans = Loan::select('date_release')->where('invalid',false)->where('transaction_year', $transyear);
if(!empty($loantype)){
  $loans = $loans->where('loan_type', $loantype); 
}   
$result = $loans->get();
```